# Java: Somehow I managed to extend a final method

Tags: java, methods, final

The Vector3 class contains this:

```
public final boolean set(float x, float y, float z) {
    setX(x);
    setY(y);
    setZ(z);
    return true;
}
```

The Vector4 class contains this:

```
public boolean set(float x, float y, float z, float w) {
    setX(x);
    setY(y);
    setZ(z);
    setW(w);
    return true;
}
```

No errors. Why?

Comment: I should note that Vector4 extends Vector3.

Comment: You don't "extend" methods.  You override them.  (And in this case you overloaded the method instead of overriding it.)

Answer (score 4):

You didn't override `set` in `Vector4`.  You overloaded it.  `Vector4`'s `set` method has 4 parameters but `Vector3`'s `set` method has 3 parameters.  There is no error because no method is attempting to override the `final` `set` method in `Vector3`.

Answer (score 1):

You did not extend the method, but instead you have created a new overloaded method with a different signature. Although they may have the same name, the fact that their parameter lists are different makes them distinct methods.

Had you attempted to override Vector3.set(float, float, float) with:

```
public boolean set(float x, float y, float z)
```

in Vector4, there would have been an error at compilation.